# DataTable with Server-side processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

My current problem is how could I properly perform pagination in DataTable to generate lengthMenu `(Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries)` dynamically and only load data when next page is clicked.

So far my understanding on server-side processing is like this:
**My web service is returning data from database using MySQL with limit and offset in JSON format**. 
Assuming that the JSON data is correct how could I properly paginate my DataTable?

Below is my code:

```
var Table1 = $('#table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": SomeWorkingURLS,
        "dataType": "jsonp"
    },

    "columns": [
        { "data": "Column1" },
        { "data": "Column2" },
        { "data": "Column3" },
        { "data": "Column4" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return data + "<hr>" + row.data1;
            },
            "targets": 0
        },
        {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return data + "<br>" + row.data2 ;
            },
            "targets": 1
        },
        {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return  data ;
            },
            "targets": 2
        },
        {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {

                if (row.status == '2'){

                return '<button class="fas fa-edit btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" value="' + data + '">Verify</button>'
                + ' <button class="fas fa-undo btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Resend" value="' + data + '"> Authenticate</button>';

                }
                else{
                    return '<button class="fas fa-edit btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" value="' + data + '">Authenticate</button>';
                }

            },
            "targets": 3
        },
        { "width": "14%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "60%", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "10%", "targets": 2 },
        { "width": "16%", "targets": 3 , "class":"dt-center"},
    ],

    "destroy": true,
    "searching" :false

    });

    Table1.draw();
    $("select[name*='table_outbound_shipment_list']").removeClass('form-control');
    $("#table_outbound_shipment_list_length").remove();
    $('.form-control.form-control-sm').removeClass('form-control');
```

My web service would always return 10 row of data (or am I doing wrong here?)

 My reference:https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries and helper classes for server-side processing that help with preparing server-side response.

For example, DataTables distribution includes [ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) helper calss and [sample script](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php) to aid in generating response if you're using PHP.

Otherwise, you can inspect [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) and paginate your results based on `start` and `length` request parameters.